# Swift - Attempting to change UITableView row height dynamically but heightForRowAtIndexPath never gets called

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I've been trying for over a day now to change the row height dynamically of a UITableView cell depending on the amount of text that is in a label contained within the cell. I've tried numerous suggestions from websites and videos to no avail. The function heightForRowAtIndexPath never gets called for some reason even though cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called every time.

Here is some code I've just been using to see if I could get results to change during runtime. The values you see are just for testing. The main issue I'm facing with this portion is that the entire function does not get called even though the UITableViewDelegate is set up properly.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let cell: VCNewsFeedCell = tvPosts.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewsFeedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as VCNewsFeedCell

    cell.lblDescription.setNeedsLayout()
    cell.lblDescription.layoutIfNeeded()

    var size: CGSize = cell.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)

    return 500
}
```

I've also tried the newer methods for dynamically increasing the row height for iOS8, but that hasn't worked either. The methods I tried for this include the following lines of code placed in the viewDidLoad function:

```
    self.tvPosts.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tvPosts.estimatedRowHeight = 350
```

Neither of the above methods have done anything to change the height of the row.

As a side note, I have successfully placed constraints on all of the user interface items contained in the table view cell and as a result, all of the user interface items show up in the proper location at runtime and they move properly according to the amount of text in a label which is also contained in the table cell.

In summary, I'm able to get all of the user interface components contained within a custom UITableViewCell to move properly according to the amount of text contained with a label in the cell, but the cell itself remains the same size every time which causes the user interface components to sometimes overrun the bounds of the cell and get placed in the next cell below it.

Any suggestions on what I can try?

Comment: Can you plz remove the code **return 500**, and put **return size.height**

Comment: I've tried that also and it didn't work because the function is never called. I changed the return value to a constant of 500 just to see if that would do anything. But, when I placed a breakpoint on the beginning of the function, it showed that the code never executed at runtime.

Comment: Have you tried out to do it by dynamic hight calculating, and remove Auto-layout constraints?

Comment: I haven't tried anything where the auto layout constraints are removed because my understanding is that the auto layout constraints are needed in order to calculate the dynamic size of the cell. Can you explain further?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a UILable in tableviewcell, So just remove all auto layout constraints, and calculate the hight required to set uilalbe in border of uitableviewcell like this,

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:yourLabel.font 
                    constrainedToSize: CGRectMake(UILable.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX) 
                    lineBreakMode:yourLabel.lineBreakMode];

    return  expectedLabelSize.height; //You can add padding size like in top and bottom.
}
```

Hope this helps you,

HTH, Happy Coding!!

Comment: I can try that. The main problem that still exists though is that the heightForRowAtIndexPath function never gets called. I've verified that the tableView delegate is set both in the code and in IB. For some reason, the code never executes when verified by placing a breakpoint at the beginning of the function. I can't figure out why it won't execute.

Comment: This is silly que from me, but it may be the prblm,  have you set class to view controller?

Comment: Yes, it is set to the proper view controller and the code calls cellForIndexPath properly, but it doesn't call heightForRowAtIndexPath at all. I've got both the delegate and datasource set for the tableView. It is my understanding that cellForRowAtIndexPath is a datasource method while heightForRowAtIndexPath is a delegate method. This could mean there may be a problem with the setup of the delegate, but I'm not sure how that can be since the tableView delegate is set in both the code and in IB.